# Spring + JPA many to many relationship

Tags: spring, list, jpa, many-to-many

I'm very new to Spring and I'm trying to make a many-to-many relationship work as I expect. The relationships works fine, the tables are created and the data is inserted correctly. What I expect, is that when I empty a List (i.e. I empty the ArrayList "users" from an object of type "Group"), I expect the system to remove the relationships from the database - but it doesn't.

I have the following classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`group`")
public class Group
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "`user_has_group`",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "`user`")
public class User
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<Group>();

    ...
}
```

Here are the DAOs:

```
@Repository
public class GroupJpaDao implements GroupDao
{
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void save(Group group)
    {
        this.em.merge(group);
    }

    ...

    @PersistenceContext
    void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager)
    {
        this.em = entityManager;
    }
}

@Repository
public class UserJpaDao implements UserDao
{
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void save(User user)
    {
        this.em.merge(user);
    }

    ...

    @PersistenceContext
    void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager)
    {
        this.em = entityManager;
    }
}
```

Here is the test method:

```
@Test
public void test()
{
    Group g = new Group();
    g.setName("Test group");
    groupDao.save(g); // Works fine - inserts the group into the database

    User u = new User();
    u.setName("Test user");
    userDao.save(u); // Works fine - inserts the user into the database

    g.addUser(u);
    groupDao.save(g); // Works fine - adds the many-to-many relationship into the database

    g.removeAllUsers();
    groupDao.save(g); // Doesn't work - I'm expecting it to remove all the related relationships from the database but it doesn't!
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it something not possible to do?

Any hint is really appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: did you try adding `delete-orphan` to your cascade `attribute`?

Comment: Did you declared `IdTransferringMergeEventListener`?

Comment: Don't know if that's the cause of the problem, but the save method shouldn't return void. It should return the result of the merge call. Try doing this change and using the returned group : `g = groupDao.save(g);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reread your question, and now the answer is clear. Your create a Group `g`, and save it. But since your save method uses `merge`, and you don't take into account the value returned by `merge` to assign it to `g`, you keep merging the transient group g, which never has any ID assigned. So, each time merge is called, you actually create a new group rather than modifying the previously created one.

Change the save method to

```
public Group save(Group group)
{
    return this.em.merge(group);
}
```

and always reassign the result to `g`:

```
g = groupDao.save(g);
```

Of course, the same must be done for the user.

Answer (score 0):

you're only removing the users from the group, that's not enough. you need to remove all the users from the group *and remove that group from all those users' list of groups*.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary, since the owning side is the group.

Comment: are you sure? it's manytomany after all. satoshi, can you please try this! i must admit i didn't test it first :/

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The documentation says: "If the association is bidirectional, one side has to be the owner and one side has to be the inverse end (ie. it will be ignored when updating the relationship values in the association table):"